# TVP not returning recordset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

This is the first time I'm trying to use a TVP for SQL Server. I'm running SQL Server 2016 Developer edition.

Here is my custom type and sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TranslateListOne] AS TABLE (TestOne INT)

CREATE PROCEDURE Translator_SaveTextToSQLOne 
    (@TranslatorListOne TranslateListOne READONLY)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM @TranslatorListOne
```

To debug, I'm running SQL Server Profiler. Here is the output:

```
declare @p3 dbo.TranslateListOne
insert into @p3 values(5)
insert into @p3 values(3)

exec sp_executesql N'Translator_SaveTextToSQLOne',N'@TranslatorListOne [TranslateListOne] READONLY',@TranslatorListOne=@p3
```

When I run the SQL Server Profiler in a new query window, it should list the table `@TranslatorListOne`. Nothing is being output, and I'm not getting an error either. Before calling `exec sp_executesql`, if you add a

```
select * from @p3
```

The table is filled correctly before calling the stored procedure. What am I missing?

**UPDATED**

I'm using asp.net to call the stored procedure. What am I missing in this code?  It's not returning the records that I send it.

```
Dim dbMain As New SqlConnection(GetConnection)
Dim rsReader As SqlDataReader
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Translator_SaveTextToSQLOne", dbMain)
Dim myTable As New DataTable
myTable.Columns.Add("TestOne", GetType(Integer))
myTable.Rows.Add(5)
myTable.Rows.Add(3)
Dim myParam As New SqlParameter("@TranslatorListOne", SqlDbType.Structured)
myParam.TypeName = "TranslateListOne"
myParam.Value = myTable
cmd.Parameters.Add(myParam)
dbMain.Open()
rsReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While rsReader.Read
'Read the rows
End While
```

Comment: Try doing `EXEC Translator_SaveTextToSQLOne @p3` after inserting values in @p3.

Comment: why the query select * from @p3 does not showing result, maybe the local variable is not shared in public, so not accessed on query window. in my case, the TVP multi column is filled but ordered randomly not matched with column name. https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/306

Answer (score 2):

If you are anything like me, you are going to hit yourself on the forehead in 3...2...1...:

You need to add the variable to `sp_execute_sql` as a part of the statement as well:

```
exec sp_executesql N'Translator_SaveTextToSQLOne @TranslatorListOne', 
                                          --     ^ This is missing ^
                   N'@TranslatorListOne [TranslateListOne] READONLY',
                   @TranslatorListOne=@p3
```

Took me a few searches and a few test runs to finally figure this one out...

Comment: This is a tested, working solution. I wonder why it got a downvote.

Comment: I was looking at where I earned my -1 . Seems I down voted instead of up voting. @Zohar Regret this. But you'd need to edit the answer so that I can change my vote.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi No worries! I don't really get offended when I get downvotes, but I usually appreciate them better if they come with a comment specifying what's wrong with my answer...